# Count of permutations such that there exist pair $x, y$ such $A_x > y$ and $A_y > x$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Here's an interesting combinatoric problem I have no clue about:

> How many permutations of $1, 2, 3, ..., 19, 20$ exist such that the $5$th element is $7$, and the $10$th element is $14$, and there exists at least one pair of $x, y$ such that $x < y$, $A_x > y$ and $A_y > x$ where $A$ is the permutation.

I have been thinking of this for a while without many ideas. I think if we can somehow count all the permutations, we should be able to remove those that don't satisfy the other constraint.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the notation properly, but does the following work? If $A_{11} > 10$ then since $A_{10} = 14 > 11$, so $10,11$ is such a pair. Similarly, for $A_{12}$ and $A_{13}$. Otherwise, if $A_{11},A_{12},A_{13} \leq 10$ then there must be a number $i$, $1 \leq i \leq 9$ such that $A_i > 10$, and since $A_{10} = 14 > i$, $i,10$ is our pair.